# Como criar uma função que retorne a menor data de validade entre os lotes de um determinado produto?

Tags: mysql, sql, banco-de-dados, funções, trigger

Como eu crio uma função que retorne a menor data de validade entre os lotes de um determinado produto?

Seque o meu código SQL:

```
create database Exemplo;

use Exemplo;
create table produto
(codProduto integer not null,
 nomeProduto varchar(50) not null,
 marca varchar(50) not null,
 precoCusto decimal(15,2) not null,
 precoVenda decimal(15,2) not null,
 primary key (codProduto));
```

---

```
 create table loteproduto
 (codProduto integer not null,
  codLote integer not null,
  nuLote char(10) not null,
  dtValidade date,
  primary key (codProduto, codLote),
  foreign key (codProduto) references produto(codProduto));
```

---

```
insert into produto (codProduto, nomeProduto, Marca, precoCusto, precoVenda) 
values (1, 'Inseticida 500 ML', 'SBP',4,7),
       (2, 'Pastilha refil', 'SBP', 2,4),
       (3, 'Refrigerante guaranÃ¡', 'Pureza', 3,5),    
       (4, 'Refrigerante laranja', 'Pureza', 3,5),
       (5, 'Amaciante amarelo', 'Downy', 6,9),
       (6, 'Amaciante rosa', 'Downy', 4,5),
       (7, 'Frango', 'Sadia', 5,10),
       (8, 'Peru', 'Sadia', 5,10);
```

---

```
insert into loteproduto (codProduto, codLote, nuLote, dtValidade) 
values (1, 1, '399A',null),
       (1, 2, '323A','2012-12-31'),
       (2, 1, 'EF2A','2012-12-30'),
       (7, 1, 'EF3A',null);
```

Answer (score 1):

Logicamente você precisa retornar isso (e filtrar se necessário por parâmetros) ou um registro ou uma tabela como abaixo:

```
  DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `ObterLoteMinimo`;
  CREATE PROCEDURE `ObterLoteMinimo`(IN inCodigoProduto integer, IN inCodLote integer)

  -- por produto e lote
  select
       codProduto,
       codLote,
       min(dtValidade)
  from
       loteproduto
  where
       codLote = inCodLote,
       codProduto = inCodigoProduto 
  group by
        codProduto, codLote;
```

Comment: Eu gostaria de fazer isso através de uma create function

Comment: @Jarwin estou mais acostumado com a sintaxe do SQL Server, mas acredito que isto deve ser o suficiente para utilizar com o php.

Answer (score 0):

**Utilizando `function`:**

```
delimiter $
create function getMenorDataValidade(p_codProduto integer) returns date
begin
    return (select min(loteproduto.dtValidade)
            from loteproduto
            where loteproduto.codProduto = p_codProduto);
end
$ delimiter ;
```